# Azure Vnet Peering across subscriptions using Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-virtual-network, terraform-provider-azure

I was wondering if someone could help me with setting up Vnet Peerings across subscriptions in Azure using Terraform. Each subscription is within the same tenant, but they have different service principals. I keep getting errors suggesting that the service principal cannot see the resource group in the other subscription. This is despite giving that service principal contributor access to the other subscription.

This is an example of the code I have:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network_peering" "dev-to-test" {
  name                      = "dev-to-test"
  resource_group_name       = "gl-dev-rg"
  virtual_network_name      = "gl-dev-vnet"
  remote_virtual_network_id = "/subscriptions/subscriptionid/resourceGroups/gl-test-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/gl-test-vnet"
  allow_virtual_network_access = true
  allow_forwarded_traffic   = true
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network_peering" "test-to-dev" {
  name                      = "test-to-dev"
  resource_group_name       = "gl-test-rg"
  virtual_network_name      = "gl-test-vnet"
  remote_virtual_network_id = "/subscriptions/subscriptionid/resourceGroups/gl-dev-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/gl-dev-vnet"
  allow_virtual_network_access = true
  allow_forwarded_traffic   = true
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Further information can be found here:
https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/1253

Comment: You pointed that the sp cannot access the rgs. Did you assign a contributor role in both subscriptions?

Comment: Yes, the one subscription does have access to the other one. I seem to hit the issue when building the first peering. Which is the one where dev sp has access to the test subscription

Comment: This is being addressed in the related GitHub issue for this [here](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/1253). We will repost the final solution once the issue is resolved.

Comment: Use multiple providers like [this](https://robertdebock.nl/learn-terraform/ADVANCED/multiple-resources.html).

Answer (score 1):

The question was asked and answered in this [issue](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/1253). The TL;DR is terraform has an [alias](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/providers.html#alias-multiple-provider-instances) parameter for providers. This allows two separate service principals to reference different resources in a single terraform run.